# Comparing three columns in Excel and returning the differences

Tags: vba, excel

I am sure you have heard this phrase before "I am new to Excel VBA and would like to ask for assistance on how to do the following.

I have an `A` column that contains numbers, a `B` column that contains a name, and a C column that contains numbers of the same makeup of column A.  Columns B and C are sort of a record and column A is a standalone that will be compared to Column C.   Example

```
Column A      Column B   Column C    OutputColumn MW1   OutputColumn MW2  OutputColumn MW3

1020          MW1        1020          1020              (1020)             (1020)
2020          MW1        3020          (2020)            2020               (2020)
3020          MW2        2020          3020              (3020)              3020
              MW2        3020
              MW3        3020
```

What I need to do is compare each row in column A against each recordset for Column B and C and send the information to output columns based upon name used in Column B -  What I need to show in summation is what values exist for each name and which do not - The ones in parenthesis do not match -  The example above explains what I mean hopefully.

I wrote code to try and do this but I'm either getting incorrect, missing values or too many duplicates - As a side note where I used naming such as `ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellM").Value = val1`, it's a named manager value that finds the last line entered and places the data to the following row in the specified column

Originally all of the devices were in the same loop but I broke them out thinking that might resolve the duplicates. I also added a switch column to try and keep track of what rows have already been processed but that did not work either.  Not shown here is the idea of keeping track of the previous record number so that when it loops through again it will skip the records already processed.

I hope this is enough information and also hope its not to much -  Can someone push me in the right direction?  Am I overcomplicating this process?

```
Loop and print the FTN's

   For Each a In Range("B2:B4")
         If Trim(a.Value) = "" Then
         Exit For
         End If
         ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellK").Value = a.Value
      Next

  Range("K2:K1000").ClearContents
  Range("M2:M1000").ClearContents
  Range("O2:O1000").ClearContents
  Range("Q2:Q1000").ClearContents
  Range("S2:S1000").ClearContents
  'Loop Through the List of FTN
  Count = 2
  For Each b In Range("B2:B4")
   If Trim(b.Value) = "" Then
     Exit For
   End If

   'Loop Through DeviceName records looking for Device MCW001
    Count = 2
    For Each d In Range("D2:D10")
       val1 = ""
       val1 = Cells(Count, 8).Value
       Checked = ""
       Checked = Cells(Count, 3).Value

       If Trim(d.Value) = "" Then
       Exit For
       End If

       If Checked = "" Then
          If Trim(d.Value) = "MCW001" Then
              If Trim(val1) = Trim(b.Value) Then
                  ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellM").Value = val1
                  Count = Count + 1
                   ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellC").Value = "Y"
                  Exit For
              Else
                  txt = "-" & Trim(b.Value)
                  ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellM").Value = txt
                  Count = Count + 1
                  ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellC").Value = "Y"
                  Exit For
              End If
          Else
              ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellC").Value = "Y"
          End If

        End If
        Count = Count + 1

     Next
  Next

     Count = 2
     Range("C2:C1000").ClearContents
     For Each b In Range("B2:B4")
      If Trim(b.Value) = "" Then
        Exit For
      End If
      Count = 2
       Range("C2:C1000").ClearContents

      'Loop Through DeviceName records looking for Device MCW002
       For Each d In Range("D2:D10")
          val1 = ""
          val1 = Cells(Count, 8).Value
          lastval = ""
          lastval = Cells(Count, 3).Value
          If Trim(d.Value) = "" Then
          Exit For
          End If

          If (Trim(d.Value) = "MCW002") Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellC").Value = "Y"
           If lastval <> "Y" Then

              ' Add FTN or X accordingly
               If Trim(val1) = Trim(b.Value) Then
                   ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellO").Value = val1
                   Count = Count + 1
                   Exit For
               Else
                   txt = "-" & Trim(b.Value)
                   ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellO").Value = txt
                   Count = Count + 1

                   Exit For
               End If

             End If

          End If
           Count = Count + 1

      Next


     Next

     Count = 2
      Range("C2:C1000").ClearContents
     Range("C2:C1000").ClearContents
     For Each b In Range("B2:B4")
      If Trim(b.Value) = "" Then
        Exit For
      End If
      Count = 2
       Range("C2:C1000").ClearContents

      'Loop Through DeviceName records looking for Device MCW003
       For Each d In Range("D2:D10")
          val1 = ""
          val1 = Cells(Count, 8).Value
          lastval = ""
          lastval = Cells(Count, 3).Value
          If Trim(d.Value) = "" Then
          Exit For
          End If

          If (Trim(d.Value) = "MCW003") Then
             ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellC").Value = "Y"
            If lastval <> "Y" Then

              ' Add FTN or X accordingly
               If Trim(val1) = Trim(b.Value) Then
                   ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellQ").Value = val1

                   Count = Count + 1
                   Exit For
               Else
                   txt = "-" & Trim(b.Value)
                   ActiveSheet.Range("LastCellQ").Value = txt

                   Count = Count + 1
                   Exit For
               End If

             End If

          End If
           Count = Count + 1

      Next


     Next


  End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of spending time apologizing for being so new, next time you ask a question, **review your post**.  There were several grammatical errors that made your question confusing, particularly the missing commas in the second paragraph.  It's also rambling and is a bit exhausting to follow.  The more effort you put in making the question good, the more likely someone will *want* to answer you.  Review the suggestions on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Load each column to a **Dictionary**, then use the method **Exists** to check if the value is present in that column.

Example comparing two columns:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Set gplsBooks = New Dictionary
    Set pegasusBooks = New Dictionary

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'fill a dictionary with the content of the first column
    Call populateCollection(sheet, 1, 2, pegasusBooks)

    'fill a dictionary with the content of the second column
    Call populateCollection(sheet, 2, 2, gplsBooks)

    'print the values that exist only in the first column
    Call printDifference(sheet, pegasusBooks, gplsBooks, 3, 2)

    'print the values that exist only in the second column
    Call printDifference(sheet, gplsBooks, pegasusBooks, 4, 2)
End Sub

Private Sub populateCollection(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, column As Integer, initialRow As Integer, ByVal list As Dictionary)

    row = initialRow
    Value = sheet.Cells(row, column).Value

    Do While Value <> Empty
        If Not list.Exists(CStr(Value)) Then
            list.Add CStr(Value), CStr(Value)
        End If
        row = row + 1
        Value = sheet.Cells(row, column).Value
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub printDifference(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, ByVal list1 As Dictionary, ByVal list2 As Dictionary, column As Integer, initialRow As Integer)

    row = initialRow

    For Each Item In list1.items
        If Not list2.Exists(Item) Then
            sheet.Cells(row, column).Value = Item
            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Before executing:

```
Pegasus_Books Gpls_Books    Only_in_Pegasus     Only_in_Gpls
A               A           
B               B           
C               F
D               G
```

After executing:

```
Pegasus_Books Gpls_Books    Only_in_Pegasus     Only_in_Gpls
A               A           C                   F
B               B           D                   G
C               F
D               G
```